# Magento 1.7 doesn't return token key

Tags: api, oauth, rest-api

I installed magento 1.7 and test for rest api according to this link. 
http://www.aschroder.com/2012/04/introduction-to-the-magento-rest-apis-with-oauth-in-version-1-7/

When I request to this

http://demo.io/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=mbmuatb1a9704p94pfpqy48i2uv8s2vg 
It redirect to home page and return nothing.

If anyone know, help me plz. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I will shoot in the dark here, but most probably you have the flag `Auto-redirect to Base URL` set to `Yes` under `System->Configuration->Web->Url Options`. and when you are calling the authorize url, the Base url you are using is not the same as the base url set in the backend.
Check if you are missing the `www` or something similar.